# IF Else conditional is not working on second click

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, if-statement

Jquery else conditional not working. when I click `#webul li` the first time the background position changes to `0 144` but when i click again nothing happens.

```
$('.design-button').click(function() {
    $('#webul li ').not('.design').toggle(500)
    if($('.design-button').css("background-position", "0 0px")){
        $('.design-button').css("background-position", "0 144px")
    }
    else {
        $(".design-button").css("background-position", "0 0px")
    }
});
```

Comment: Using a setter which returns a jQuery object inside a conditional will always evaluate to true.

Comment: your if statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: What the above poster is saying is that your conditional should be `if($('.design-button').css('background-position') == "0 0px")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.design-button').css("background-position", "0 0px")){
```

is always **true**.. You are not checking for a value here , you are assigning it and that makes the statement always true  .. Make this change

```
if($('.design-button').css("background-position") == "0 0px")){
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll also note it fails if you don't add the px to the attributes. This should work. Though, depending on intended functionality, you may consider changing the internal identifiers to $(this) instead of $('.design-button')

```
$('.design-button').click(function() {   
     $('#webul li ').not('.design').toggle(500);

    if($('.design-button').css("background-position") == "0px 0px"){         
        $('.design-button').css("background-position", "144px"); 
     } 
    else { 
         $('.design-button').css("background-position", "0px 0px");
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kJ7Ew/3/